# Set a JS cookie if a specific class exists in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, jquery-cookie

I am trying to set the JS cookie if a specific class exists in a document. The cookie script is working but it's not applying to the class match logic.

Code:

```
(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';
    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
        var d = new Date(); 
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*1000*60*60*24)); 
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString(); 
        window.document.cookie = cname+"="+JSON.stringify(cvalue)+"; "+expires;
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "="; 
        var cArr = window.document.cookie.split(";"); 
        for(var i=0; i<cArr.length; i++) {
            var c = cArr[i].trim();
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0){ 
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }    
        }
        return "";
    }
    function deleteCookie(cname) {
        var d = new Date(); 
        d.setTime(d.getTime() - (1000*60*60*24)); 
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString(); 
        window.document.cookie = cname+"="+"; "+expires;
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
           var ele = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
           for(var i=0;i<ele.length;i++){
                var classes = ele[i].getAttribute('class');
                var fclass = "smcx-iframe-container";
                console.log(classes);
                if(classes = fclass){
                    var cookieval = getCookie('device-t-ban');
                    if( cookieval === "" ){
                        var fp = new Fingerprint({
                              canvas: true,
                              ie_activex: true,
                              screen_resolution: true
                            });
                        var uid = fp.get();
                        setCookie('device-t-ban',uid,1);  
                        console.log('no cookie!');
                        console.log(getCookie('device-t-ban'));
                    }else if(cookieval != ""){
                        $(".smcx-iframe-container").html("<div class='tryagain'><p>Try again in 24 hours!</p></div>");
                        console.log('yes cookie!');
                        console.log(getCookie('device-t-ban'));
                    }
                    
                } else {
                    exist = 'class not available'
                }     
           }
       }, 3000);
    });
})( jQuery );
```

I am unable to figure out why it's not working. It seems something to do with the class match.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Seems like it'd be easier to check `$(".smcx-iframe-container").length`, which will be zero if the class is not found and non-zero if one or more elements have it. Also checking the entire `class` attribute value won't work in general, as an element can have many classes.

Comment: To be clear, you don't have to iterate through all the elements; jQuery will do that for you (and so will the browser itself if you use `.getElementsByClassName()`).

Comment: `if(classes = fclass)` is an assignment, not a comparison.

Comment: in header this exists: .smcx-embed>.smcx-iframe-container{
 max-width: 100%!important;
} Can this be a problem?

Comment: No that's a CSS rule, it will affect the layout but not the code you posted.

Comment: Tried this var getelement = document.getElementsByClassName("smcx-iframe-container");
           if(getelement){
            console.log('exists');
           } else {
            console.log('not exists');
           } Didnt work

Comment: @mysticalghoul that would work if you used `if (getelement.length)`

Comment: Ok thats working now the if statement with cookie not working properly if(getelement.length){
                if(getCookie('device-t-ban')){

Comment: What's not working properly about this if-statement? Is there an error? Or not executing when you're expecting it to?

Comment: The inner if statement: if the cookie is set

Comment: Ok got it had to set cookie with PHP and used it in a ajax function